# Java final & Safe Publication

Tags: java, final, safe-publication

When I read [jsr-133-faq](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight), in question "How do final fields work under the new JMM?", it said:

```
class FinalFieldExample {
  final int x;
  int y;
  static FinalFieldExample f;
  public FinalFieldExample() {
    x = 3;
    y = 4;
  }
  static void writer() {
    f = new FinalFieldExample();
  }
  static void reader() {
    if (f != null) {
      int i = f.x;
      int j = f.y;
    }
  }
}
```

*The class above is an example of how final fields should be used. A thread executing reader is guaranteed to see the value 3 for f.x, because it is final. It is not guaranteed to see the value 4 for y, because it is not final.*

This makes me confused, because the code in writer is not safe publication, thread executing reader may see f is not null, but the constructor of the object witch f referenced is not finished yet, so even if x is final, the thread executing reader can not be guaranteed to see the value 3 for f.x.

This is the place where I'm confused, pls correct me if i am wrong, thank you very much.

Comment: `thread executing reader may see f is not null, but the constructor of the object witch f referenced is not finished yet` This can't happen, the assignment happens __after__ the constructor ran to completion and no exception was thrown.

Comment: Which mechanism ensures the occurrence of  the assignment happens after the constructor ran to completion？[In Jeremy Manson's blog](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/05/double-checked-locking.html), he said that compiler transformations can change the code around so that the code in the Helper constructor occurs after the write to the helper variable. I think the code in jsr-133-faq is the same scene with the code in Jeremy Manson's blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the whole point, and that is what's great about about final fields in the JMM. Yes, compiler can generally assign a reference to the object before the object is even fully constructed, and this is *unsafe* publication because the object may be accessed in a partially-constructed state. However, for *final* fields, the JMM (and the compiler) guarantees that all final fields will be prepared *first*, **before** assigning the reference to the object. The publication may still be unsafe and the object still only partially constructed when a new thread accesses it, but at least the final fields will be in their expected state. From chapter 16.3 in Java Concurrency in Practice:

> Initialization safety makes visibility guarantees only for the values
>   that are reachable through final fields as of the time the constructor
>   finishes. For values reachable through nonfinal fields, or values that
>   may change after construction, you must use synchronization to ensure
>   visibility.

I also recommend reading chapter 16.3 for more detail.

Comment: it seems to me that in 2014 (10 years after the book you are mentioning) the JMM specifications have changed and as long as there is one final field, it sets a barrier that doesn't allow the object to be visible (i.e. referenced) until it is properly constructed.

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/ae45df3285c9/src/share/vm/opto/parse1.cpp#l930